# Get foreign key from table reference in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes

I have a table of institutes and a table of locations. I extracted the data from spreadsheets and currently have the following information:

```
Institute

id, name, ukprn

Location

id, name, ukprn, lat, long, institute
```

`ukprn` is the unique id given through the government, but some institutes in the future may not have this so I don't want to specifically use it as a reference. What I think I need to do is for the Location.institute attribute to contain the Institute.id where Institute.ukprn and Location.ukprn match, but I'm not sure how this would work and save it to the code.

I tried:

```
Location.each do |location|
  if location.ukprn == Institute.ukprn then
    put Institute.id => Location.institute
  end
end
```

This comes up with an undefined method 'each' error. I'm clearly doing something wrong, but not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `undefined method each error` because Location as a model class don't have each method. There are other things which are wrong in your code.

You have to do this in a following way,

```
Institute.find_each do |institute|
  Location.where(ukprn: institute.ukprn).update_all(institute_id: institute.id)
end
```

In above code for each institute you are checking for `ukprn` corresponding to all locations, every matched location's institute_id will be updated with institute id.

Comment: You can consider using find_each instead of all.each. That way it will be more faster and will have less memory footprint during runtime.

Comment: @SatyamSingh Yes. you are right. Updated my answer.

Comment: That's worked perfectly. Thanks for both the code and the explanation guys!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to call each method on a class. First get all the locations and institutes and do something like below:

```
@locations = Location.all
@institutes = Institute.all

@locations.each do |location|
  @institutes.each do |institute|
   if location.ukprn == institute.ukprn
     institute.id = location.institute
     institute.save!
   end 
  end
end
```

I guess there might be a better way to optimize the lookup by not using each to loop over each record, e.g., you can delete/mark a record as "processed" and then later get just get the "unprocessed" records so your array size will reduce in the subsequent `each` loop.

hope it helps! let me know if you are looking like this.